# Converting a string to ISO 8601 duration format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, iso

I need to allow users to type a string like this:

> 1m 3w 4d 22h 6m 3s

… and then convert it to ISO 8601 duration format, like this:

```
P1M3W4DT22H6M3S
```

They should even be allowed to write shorter notation, like:

> 10d 12h

I don’t even know where to start with this, and can’t seem to find any library that helps with these conversions. I can use Moment to convert *from* ISO 8601 duration format, but not *to*.

Suggestions?

I tried to just remove spaces, but of course I’m missing the `T` before time:

```js
`P${duration.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '')}`
```

Comment: Looks too complicated but what have you tried yet?

Comment: Can't you provide date time selector to users?

Comment: I brief is to allow for this type of string. I’m trying to stick to it, but not sure it’s possible.

Comment: What if input is "10m"? Is that 10 minutes or 10 months? Secondly, is the order of the parts in the input guaranteed to be from large unit to small unit?

Comment: @trincot — I would have to say minutes takes precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spaces have been removed and letters have been capitalised, you can use the regular expression [`\d+H?\d*M?\d*S?$`](https://regex101.com/r/RvVwPl/1) to capture the time part of the input, when there is one. This determines the insertion point for the "T" delimiter:

```js
const toDuration = s => "P" + s.toUpperCase(s).replace(/\s/g, "")
                               .replace(/\d+H?\d*M?\d*S?$/, "T$&");

console.log(toDuration("1m 3w 4d 22h 6m 3s"));
console.log(toDuration("10d 12h"));
console.log(toDuration("10m"));
console.log(toDuration("1y 8w 3d"));
console.log(toDuration("2m 12h"));
```

Some assumptions are made:

- If the input leaves ambiguity over the meaning of "m" (months or minutes), then it is interpreted as minutes.
- The order of the parts in the input does not need changing for deriving a valid period notation.
- The input follows the format as given in the example. There is no input validation here.

If you want to include validation, then extend like this:

```js
const toDuration = s => /^(\d+y\s*)?(\d+m\s*)?(\d+w\s*)?(\d+d\s*)?(\d+h\s*)?(\d+m\s*)?(\d+s\s*)?$/i.test(s)
                ? "P" + s.toUpperCase(s).replace(/\s/g, "")
                         .replace(/\d+H?\d*M?\d*S?$/, "T$&")
                : ""; // indicates bad format

console.log(toDuration("1m 3w 4d 22h 6m 3s"));
console.log(toDuration("10d 12h"));
console.log(toDuration("10m"));
console.log(toDuration("1y 8w 3d"));
console.log(toDuration("2m 12h"));
console.log(toDuration("bad12 format"));
```

Comment: This is gold, but unless you count in for some input validation. In example, `toDuration('')` gives you `P` and `toDuration('bullshit')` gives you `PBULLSHIT` :-)

Comment: Of course, this assumes the input is formatted as in the original post.

Comment: I can probably validate it as a date with moment.

Comment: Added a version that will return an empty string when the input does not have the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're missing is `T` separator after `D` mark, simply add `.replace('D', 'DT')}`.

```js
let duration = '1m 3w 4d 22h 6m 3s'
`P${duration.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '').replace('D', 'DT')}`
// gives 'P1M3W4D22H6M3S'
```

But this only works for static input format.

---

For parsing both complete and incomplete inputs, you need to parse them by type.

```js
const parseDuration = duration => {
  const keys = ['Y', 'M', 'W', 'D', 'H', 'MIN', 'S']
  if (!duration || typeof duration !== 'string')
    throw "Empty input"
  let parsed = {}
  // split entries by space and process them
  duration.split(/\s+/).map(r => {
    // get length (number) and type for each entry
    let [_, len, type] = r.match(/^(\d+)(\w+)$/)
    type = type.toUpperCase()
    // assume M means minutes if either of W, D or H is set
    if (type === 'M' && (parsed['W'] || parsed['D'] || parsed['H']))
      type = 'MIN'
    // asign length by type
    if (len && keys.includes(type))
      parsed[type] = len
  })
  
  if (!Object.keys(parsed).length)
    throw new Error("Empty input")
  
  // set all undefined types to zero
  for (const k of keys)
    parsed[k] = parseInt(parsed[k]) || 0
  
  // format to ISO 8601 duration
  return `P${parsed.Y}Y${parsed.M}M${parsed.W}W${parsed.D}DT${parsed.H}H${parsed.MIN}M${parsed.S}S`
}

try {
  console.log(parseDuration('1m 3w 4d 22h 6m 3s'))
} catch {
  console.warn('failed to parse')
}
// P0Y1M3W4DT22H6M3S

try {
  console.log(parseDuration('3w 12h 10m'))
} catch {
  console.warn('failed to parse')
}
// P0Y0M3W0DT12H10M0S

try {
  console.log(parseDuration('1bullshit'))
} catch {
  console.warn('failed to parse')
}
// fails

try {
  console.log(parseDuration(''))
} catch {
  console.warn('failed to parse')
}
// fails
```

Example edited to include basic syntax validation

Comment: But D is not required. You could have a string like `3w 12h 10m`.

Comment: I see, then you need to parse the values one by one... shouldn't be complicated, gimme a moment